# set background png on Linearlayout without affecting layout size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-linearlayout

Background image doesn't fill Linearlayout and changes that size

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@mipmap/dashboard_background"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="10dp">
```

[image]

desirable look is this

[image]

How can I reach that?

Answer (score 2):

Background always stretches to its `View` size. So you can't really control how it will look like. Instead, put an `ImageView` as a bottom most (meaning that it will lay under everything else) element in your layout, and use your background image as a source (`src`) for this `ImageView`, and so you will be able to control the look of the background with `scaleType` (probable you would want to use `centerCrop` or `fitCenter`). More about `scaleType` [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide).

In the end your layout should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:src="@mipmap/dashboard_background" />

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/content_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Put your view elements here -->

  </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a frame layout with an imageview and a linearlayout inside

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background"/>

<LinearLayout
    ---Your Layout---
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works as I want, but only some elements in my layout being invisible, do you know why?

Comment: What do you mean with invisible? My guess is that your white texts are barely visible due to the bright background. Can you confirm this?

Comment: No the elements on bottom not visible  http://i.prntscr.com/7uuWI1bUQmeozpj_YWQ-lg.png

Comment: Can you provide me with your current xml?

Comment: yes of course https://codeshare.io/ado43B LifetimeStats extends from LinearLayout

Comment: I see you have two nested LinearLayouts, both with a vertical orientation. You should get rid of one and include your 

<com.fifth_llc.siply.profile.ui.LifetimeStats>

in the one layout that is left.